# Is it possible to add image to drop-down menu

Tags: image, drop-down-menu

My friend wants me to add images to her drop-down menu as seen in this WP website: http://www.absolutemakeover.com.au/ see procedures and photo gallery.

I have never done or seen this before and don't even know where to start. Could just tell her I can't do it but now I am intrigued and want to see if we can do it. Is anyone able to point us in the right direction? We are working on the site which is http://exclusiveaesthetics.weebly.com/
Cheers!

Comment: which platform you are using? specify the tag

Comment: Please add code where you are getting the problem and do refer to the [Can I paste the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)